# (Common Table Expressions) CTE as part of WHERE clause... possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use CTE in a WHERE clause e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE Table1.PK IN (
   WITH Cte AS (
    -- root selection (dynamic, generated in code)
    SELECT Bla FROM Table2
    -- recursive part
    UNION ALL
    SELECT …..)
  SELECT Bla FROM Cte)
```

The reason I’m asking is that I need to use a recursive query and the only way of doing it at the moment without updating our framework is to place it in the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, WITH clauses need to be defined before the main SELECT.  Like this:

```
WITH recursive_cte AS (
   -- root selection (dynamic, generated in code)
   SELECT Bla FROM Table2
   -- recursive part
   UNION ALL
   SELECT …..)
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE1 t
  JOIN recursive_cte rc ON rc.key = t.pk
```

I also tweaked the query to use a JOIN instead, but you'll have to watch for duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can apply WHERE CLAUSE with CTE. You have to make Table-Valued Function and return result in Table.
then you can use this result set in any query with WHERE Clause.
Go to the link and find example: 
 http://muhammadnaveed.info/use-cte-query-in-where-clause/
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice one Naveed... thanks. Having said that I'm not going to vote your answer because it's been 1265 days since I asked the question:)